# The regular expression won't work on Qt5.5

Tags: regex, qt, qregexp, qregularexpression

I want to split the string into substrings wherever blank lines occurs;

the content like this:

```
aa aa


bb bb

cc cc
```

I want to get a List like this :

List["aa aa", "bb bb", "cc cc"];

code :

```
QRegularExpression re("^(\\s*)\\n");
//or QRegularExpression re("^(\\s*)\\n\\r");
QStringList list = content.split(re);
```

The regular expression works on the notepad++, however, it won't work on Qt5.5, Windows 7 64bit;

Comment: Yeah, different regex engines often have syntax differences. Kind of defeats the purpose... Make that "not-so-regular expressions...

Comment: QRegularExpression re("\n\s*\n");  the expression meets the requirement, but It looks a bit weird.

Answer (score 0):

Just look for a newline followed by any whitespace followed by a newline over multiple lines. Other upcoming newlines in between count as whitespace here as well. The multiline option is equivalent to perls m/

```
QRegularExpression re("(\\n\\s*\\n)", QRegularExpression::MultilineOption);
```